# Mobile Safari FB.login Oauth Redirect Error

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, mobile-safari

I have a mobile web application that integrates with the Facebook Graph API.

Basically, it uses the JS SDK to obtain details about the viewing user that it can then use to render user specific content.

I use the FB.login function to have the user login to my Facebook app. This should work as follows:

JS on pages detects that user has not logged in to Facebook app

User is given button to click to fire FB.login

User is redirected to Facebook page to authorise the app and login

User is redirected back to my mobile web application

JS on pages detects that user *is* logged in to Facebook app, polls user data from Graph and renders it.

This all works fine on Android, but the redirect step does not work on Mobile Safari

The user gets an error referring to an EntityRef, which looks like the Content-type being sent to the browser is XML but where the content includes an illegal character:

Error on line 1 at column 49: EntityRef: expecting ';'

This is the actual link that is generating the error:

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&domain=cgfoodscomp.herokuapp.com&scope=email&e2e=%7B%7D&app_id=135937919902029&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&client_id=135937919902029&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D24%23cb%3Df3cf8ca2ac%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fcgfoodscomp.herokuapp.com%252Ff2d1c54b04%26domain%3Dcgfoodscomp.herokuapp.com%26relation%3Dopener%26frame%3Df35f8ac348&origin=2&response_type=token%2Csigned_request

When you open this in another browser, you get a response with Javascript (I won't post it here as it contains script tags), which contains references to the iPhone:

iPhone.*Version/(5|6)

I'm actually using a Version 4 IOS.

Does anyone know if this stuff is supposed to work in Version 4?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Facebook Bug, which is due for resolution:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/339889299473431